# Is there a colloquial phrase for a brash, over-confident person?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I'm looking for an idiom which corresponds to the English "He's got more front than Harrods". The phrase implies more than just self-confidence, but someone cheeky/brazen who will 'try it on'.

I could use "Il est effronté/éhonté", or maybe "Il est audacieux" but would prefer something more casual and idiomatic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some equivalents, roughly sorted from the more polite to the more vulgar. Some have nuances, but all means more or less "He is acting without any fear of the public opinion, because he has a too high opinion of himself"

> 1. Il est très cavalier.
> 2. Il est **sans-gène**.
> 3. Il a **du culot** / Il est **culotté**.
> 4. C'est un cow-boy.
> 5. Il est **gonflé**.
> 6. Il a les chevilles enflées.
> 7. Il se la pète / c'est un péteux.
> 8. Il ne se sent plus péter.
> 9. Il ne se prend pas pour de la merde.

1,4 are more to qualify the brash way of acting of someone.

6,7,8, are more to qualify the over-confidence of someone, whithout the "try it on" notion

2,3,5 seems closer to what you are looking for. Note that there is a subtle difference since 3 can sometimes be used in a non-pejorative way, whereas 2 and 5 are always pejorative.

Comment: Thanks for the selection and further qualification of the phrases, especially useful ordered by vulgarity!

Comment: @PapaPoule: you are absolutely right, I am adding "culotté" to this list.

Comment: "Il est gonflé" could fit as well. It's widely used and, though colloquial and informal, not vulgar at all.

Comment: I would add the belgicism "Dikkenek", translating litterally in French to "Gros-cou".

Comment: @LaurentS.: I have never seen this anywhere except in the movie of the same name, and am not aware enough about what its exact meaning is to add it to my answer. You can post your own if you want.

Answer (score 3):

"Il se la pète" is quite a common colloquial idiom for an arrogant person.